# How to do two image unlink together?

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

Below this function, I did unlink one image. now I want to unlink one more image in this function Like "**imagetwo**".

How can write code in this function for unlink **imagetwo**?

```
public function nameDeleteById($data){

    $delete_id = $data['delete_id'];

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM name WHERE id=:delete_id");
    $stmt->bindparam(":delete_id", $delete_id);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt) {
        while ($delimg=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $dellink=$delimg['image'];
            unlink($dellink);
        }
    }
    $stmt=$this->pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM name WHERE id=:delete_id");
    $stmt->bindparam(":delete_id", $delete_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt) {
        $msg = 'Name Deleted Secessfully';
        return $msg;
    } else {
        $msg = 'Name Not Deleted Secessfully';
        return $msg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question, what `imagetwo` exactly is. I'm assuming it is another column in the `name` table (?). If so, you can enhance your function like so:

```
public function nameDeleteById($data){

    $delete_id = $data['delete_id'];

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM name WHERE id=:delete_id");
    $stmt->bindparam(":delete_id", $delete_id);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt) {
        while ($delimg=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            unlink($delimg['image']);
            unlink($delimg['imagetwo']);
        }
    }
    $stmt=$this->pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM name WHERE id=:delete_id");
    $stmt->bindparam(":delete_id", $delete_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt) {
        $msg = 'Name Deleted Successfully';
        return $msg;
    } else {
        $msg = 'Name Not Deleted Successfully';
        return $msg;
    }
}
```